# Weird anomalies with mesh deform

Tags: mesh, armature

I've applied mesh deform on my mesh and I'm getting some strange results
[image]

I'm absolutely sure there are no intersecting faces and it seems that my deform mesh only affects certain vertices of my mesh

Comment: could you please tell a bit more, maybe share your file before you applied the modifier

Comment: @moonboots https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QrG4rgIA6HMMwmWgI6einnIeW1YKInqe here you go. I moved the deform to be the 1st modifier after the save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your meshes are a bit too complicated, too many vertices etc... For example, if I simplify the *MeshDeform* modifier cage, it works correctly:

[image]

Comment: how would i rig the fingers then? those are a bit tricky. any tips? is it possible to make seperate meshes just for the fingers/feet?

Comment: what do you mean? your problem had nothing to do with rigging

Comment: sorry, i constructed the question wrong. how would i go on to make simpler fingers for my deformer. I'm using the deform modifier to rig the high poly mesh and i want to be able to rig the fingers, but it really wouldnt be able to do that if i make the deformer mesh too simple

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you're going the wrong way, a mesh modifier could be useful sometimes for rigging, especially to avoid clothes overlapping, but for an object like your dragon, why don't you rig it in a classical way? I thought your mesh deform was just to adjust its shape a bit...

Comment: i was told that the best way to rig high poly objects (my mesh has around 10mil verts) is to use the mesh deform modifier. I was following the zach reinhardt's course on udemy and he did it this way. although, now i realize that he did it because he had too much parented objects... anyways, thanks for the help

Comment: I never heard that but I'm still not a 3D champion, maybe he has his reasons, but maybe first try the classical way, also try to work with less polygones, i.e. try to simplify your mesh, for example multiresolution is interesting but you need to bake it to a lower poly version

Comment: yeah, i did that, then i stored the shrinkwrap data into it